# CSS - same class looks different on other element

Tags: html, css

I created a button class named "primary". I noticed that it looks different on a `button` and on `a` tag, they have other sizes for example.

```css
.primary {
    border-radius: 0;
    color: white;
    background: #EC7404;
    padding: 9px 29px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="primary">This is a test</button>
<a class="primary">This is a test</a>
```

How can I make the class look the same on both?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/c6z8tre0/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HTML tags, browsers add their own default styles to the tags (yes, it could differ from browser to browser). In your case, there are 2 properties you need to add in the `.primary` class: '`display: inline-block and` font` properties.

As per the JSFiddle you shared. Here is the updated code and screenshot of the both elements height after the primary class code is updated:

```
.primary{
    border-radius: 0;
    color: white;
    background: #EC7404;
    padding: 9px 29px;
    /*font-size: 1.5rem;*/
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: none;

    /* these 2 lines to be added */
    display: inline-block;
    font: 400 1.5rem Arial;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx, I used `font: 400 1.5rem Arial;` that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .primary {
        border-radius: 0;
        color: white;
        background: #EC7404;
        padding: 9px 29px;
        font-family: "Goudy Bookletter 1911", sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border: none;
    }
```

```html
<button class="primary">This is a test</button>
<a class="primary">This is a test</a>
```

Comment: There is a height difference. The right button is smaller (chrome)

Answer (score 0):

This is because a browser already gives HTML elements their own style. You will overwrite this style with your own CSS. But a `button` will have a different style than an `a` element by default.

For example the line-height and font-family may be different.
And in your case it seems that `display: inline-block` will do the trick.

Comment: Thx, I tried `display: inline-block` but there is still a height difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is because elements inherit default styles, if you want the anchor to look the same simply declare the font family and font-size in your class;

```
.primary {
border-radius: 0;
color: white;
background: #EC7404;
padding: 9px 29px;
font-size: 1.5rem;
vertical-align: middle;
border: none;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 26px;
```

}